# Phantomjs parse html complex

Tags: regex, parsing, phantomjs

I want to parse a specific wesite with phantomjs :

```
<span class="sameclass">contact :</span><br>variable1<br><br />
<span class="sameclass">adresse :</span><br />variable2<br><br>
<span class="sameclass">tél : </span>variable3<br>
<span class="sameclass">email : </span><a href="mailto:a@a.com">variable4</a><br><br /> 
</td>
```

to save variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4 in array or variable in my js code.
I think i should use specific regex but i don't know how.
Thanks

Comment: Regex shouldn't be used here. You should parse the DOM directly and then you can get the text part of the DOM elements. If the DOM follows a particular pattern, you can write a function to parse out the parts you want.

Comment: Yes i know but how i can do this ?

Comment: Do you have a better HTML fragment? As it is, the current sample is not completely valid HTML. It's missing an opening `<td>` tag and the `<br>` aren't consistent.

Comment: Most languages have libraries that can be used to easily parse html (or xml).  What language are you using to parse the html?  If you are using javascript, jquery would work very well.